# Максимальное количество имплементированных интерфейсов в одном классе

Tags: java, android, jvm

Существует ли максимальное количество реализуемых интерфейсов, или их число действительно ничем не ограничено?

Answer (score 13):

Согласно выдаче гугла на запрос

> [java limit of implementing interfaces](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20limit%20of%20implementing%20interfaces)

и первой ссылке этой выдачи, ведущей на [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11034141/3212712)

В [ограничениях JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11) сказано

> The number of direct superinterfaces of a class or interface is limited to 65535 by the size of the interfaces_count item of the ClassFile structure.

Т.е. ответ - `65535` интерфейсов может один класс реализовать.

---

Но, если вы начинаете приближаться к этому пределу, то вам надо серьёзно задуматься - может быть вы что-то делаете не так.

Comment: Если топикстартер найдёт в джаве интерфейсов, хотя бы четверть,  от этого количества, то задуматся прийдётся уже разработчикам джавы :)

Comment: @Adeptius, ну, можно же ещё и свои насоздавать) Минут за пять написать код, который сгенерит нужное кол-во интерфейсов)