# Иерархия Интерфейсов

Tags: java

В книге вычитал, что иерархия интерфейсов отличается от иерархии классов, то бишь какая получается иерархия у интерфейса?

Comment: Раскройте значение слова "иерархия" в данном контексте

Comment: Я так понял , что иерархия Классов, то бишь наследования, а в интерфейсах его нет там имплиментация. Все я понял тогда!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятно что имелось в виду в приведённой цитате, но кратко дело вот как обстоит

1. Каждый класс может наследоваться только от одного другого класса.
2. Каждый класс может реализовать множество интерфейсов, вплоть до [65К штук](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/566018/17609)
3. Каждый интерфейс может наследоваться от множества интерфейсов