# Интерфейсы в Java и выделение памяти

Tags: java, интерфейс, дизайн-языка

Правильно ли следует понимать, что единственная причина, почему возможно имплементировать достаточно большое ([65535](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/566018/190461)) количество `Interface` в `Java` это то, что `Interface` не имея по определению реализации,  **не обладает памятью для хранения данных**?

Comment: Начиная с *Java 8*, интерфейс может иметь реализацию по умолчанию.

Comment: Ну, не единственная, конечно. Ещё важен [смысл](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/235464/10105).

Comment: @VladD ну конечно :), куда в программировании без смысла...

Comment: А какие могут причины, чтобы это не было возможно?

Comment: Интересна была связь с выделением памяти на хранение

Comment: Если бы с наследованием от классов поступили так же, как и с default-методами интерфейсов в Java 8, то и от нескольких классов можно бы было наследоваться.

Comment: Ограничение на кол-во интерфейсов таки есть: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566012/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5/566018#566018

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, подправлю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изначально интерфейсы это способ создать "множественное" наследование без множественного наследования. Интерфейс - это контракт, он гарантирует, что у определенного объекта есть методы с сигнатурами описанными в интерфейсе. Поскольку в java использовано понятие вызов метода, а не посылка сообщения (как в это было предложено в первой модели ООП), то компилятору нужен этот контракт для проверки кода.